# Using a dirty flag or undo stack with Knockout.js and Knockout.mapping.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, undo, kolite

I am trying to create or use an existing `dirtyFlag`. However all the examples I've seen don't talk about how to integrate them with knockout.mapping.js plugin.

There are a lot of really great examples out there like Ryan Niemeyer's stuff and John Papa's KoLite, but they all fail to answer the simple question of

> "I've got a lot of properties on my viewModel and I don't have time for hand coding
>   something that should be handled by the knockout mapping plugin"

I feel like this is a dirty (no pun intended) little secret that needs to get out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert on the knockout library but i'm a big fan of simple solutions. John Papa and Hans Fjallemarks solution in KoLite: https://github.com/CodeSeven/kolite is an excellent solution for a simple but most effective dirty flag on all or selected observables in a viewmodel.

I've done a little tweaking to it to include undo.

```
ko.DirtyFlag = function (objectToTrack, isInitiallyDirty, hashFunction) {

    hashFunction = hashFunction || ko.toJSON;

    var
        self = this,
        _objectToTrack = objectToTrack,
        _lastCleanState = ko.observable(hashFunction(_objectToTrack)),
        _isInitiallyDirty = ko.observable(isInitiallyDirty),

        result = function () {
            self.forceDirty = function () {
                _isInitiallyDirty(true);
            };

            self.isDirty = ko.computed(function () {
                return _isInitiallyDirty() || hashFunction(_objectToTrack) !== _lastCleanState();
            });

            self.reset = function () {
                _lastCleanState(hashFunction(_objectToTrack));
                _isInitiallyDirty(false);
            };

            self.undo = function () {
                var source = JSON.parse(_lastCleanState());
                for (prop in source) {
                    if (_objectToTrack[prop]() && _objectToTrack[prop]() != source[prop]) {
                        _objectToTrack[prop](source[prop]);
                    }
                }
                _isInitiallyDirty(false);
            };
            return self;
        };

    return result;
};
```

Comment: Still not sure how this an answer to my OP. I would like to get the dirty flag and/or undo added to all my observable properties (think hundreds) automatically. I DO NOT want to hand code a view model with this amount of properties (which could potentially change over time). 

So again, I am looking for a more 'automatic' or with 'knockout.mapping' way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

> "I DO NOT want to hand code a view model with this amount of properties"

I would add this as a comment above, but reputation limit...

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

> Customizing object construction using “create”
>
> If you want to handle a part of the mapping yourself, you can also provide a create callback. If this callback is present, the mapping plugin will allow you to do this part of the mapping yourself.

```
var mapping = {
    'children': {
    create: function(options) {
            var newChild = new myChildModel(options.data);
            newChild.dirtyFlag = 'add computed here';
            newChild.changeTracker = 'setup some change tracking or whatever';
            return newChild;
        }
    }
}
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
```

Thus extending the data that came from the server with custom computed obervables and the like as they pass through the mapping plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Young, I feel your pain. I stumble upon this http://jsfiddle.net/b3ky5/ on the ko github site https://github.com/knockout/knockout/wiki/Dirty-Tracking

the concept is creating a changetracker function and assigning it as a prop on your vm.

```
function changeTracker(objectToTrack, hashFunction) {    
hashFunction = hashFunction || ko.toJSON;
var lastCleanState = ko.observable(hashFunction(objectToTrack));

var result = {
    somethingHasChanged : ko.dependentObservable(function() {
        return hashFunction(objectToTrack) != lastCleanState()
    }),
    markCurrentStateAsClean : function() {
        lastCleanState(hashFunction(objectToTrack));   
    }
};

return function() { return result }
}
var viewModel = {someTextProperty: ko.observable("Hello"), boolProperty: ko.observable(false),
arrayItems: ko.observableArray([]),

addItem : function() { this.arrayItems.push("Another") }
};
viewModel.tracker = new changeTracker(viewModel);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

You still have to set the tracker but should be able to accomplish this when using ko mapping as well.

This seems a bit ugly, but the concept could set up for a better solution than none.
Hope this helps!